# XAML ListView deselected background color not working

Tags: wpf, xaml

I used this code for my listview:

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Green"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Red"/>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

However the red color is not working. It is still the default grey one.

EDIT:

also tried this:

```
 <Style x:Key="MyListView" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Style.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Green"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Green"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Red"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" Color="Red"/>
                </Style.Resources>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

With the same result.

Comment: What code/xaml are you using to assign these resources? Simply defining them as a resource will not apply them to any UI elements...

Please share more code/markup if we are to help you out.

Comment: I should have looked closer at your XAML. You don't want to assign the keys like that. Are you new to WPF? If so, I think you are asking the wrong questions. There is a lot of help available here, and these guys are brilliant...but I think you are lacking some fundamentals based on your question/example.

Comment: You just overriding default system colors. I don't think you want that. You more likely want to create style/template for listView. Take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096750/styling-listviewfor-custom-template-wpf)

Comment: mh... I found this as a solution, but I guess I understood it wrong.

I want to have a style for my listview which sets the background color of a selected item. Also when there is no focus.

Comment: found it here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/f10c6c9c-a869-42c3-8695-0f9b04bf615b/

Comment: Just like there is already. When you select sth. A blue color is applied. If you lose focus it is grey. I want to change those 2 colors for my listbox